# Create unnumbered Chapters

Tags: chapters

I want to have chapters in my book that have no number. This means it doesn't show up on the TOC and it also becomes a prefix before a section. It would look like this:

[image]

EDIT: the *it* refers to the number. So I want no chapter number but I do want the chapter title to show up on the TOC. The image is of the TOC.

Comment: So you're okay with it not showing in the ToC, or you want them added to the ToC as well?

Answer (score 3):

Use `\chapter*` (which won't be put into the ToC) instead of `\chapter` and change the `\section` numbering to not include a number based on `\chapter` .

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Vay}
  \section{one}
  \subsection{subsection}
  \section{two}
\chapter*{Woohoo}
  \section{three}
  \subsection{subsection}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:

The above solved what I thought was the OP's problem but then the OP clarified the question.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{} % from @JLeonV answer
\counterwithout{section}{chapter} % don't reset section numbers by chapter
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Vay}
  \section{one}
  \subsection{subsection}
  \section{two}
\chapter{Woohoo}
  \section{three}
  \subsection{subsection}
\end{document}
```

The above will produce unnumbered `\chapter`'s in the ToC and body of the document with `\section` and below numbered continuously.

Comment: I was unclear in my first version, so I edited it. Could you pease look again?

Comment: @FientjeVermeulen I have edited my answer following your clarified question. If you have any more clarifications please ask them in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do this is to redefine the format of the chapter counter is displayed, with the next code.

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
```

Comment: I was unclear the first time. I edited my question